# Logistic regression (with dummy variables)

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance, p-value, epidemiology

[image]

I have some problems with question (a) and (b) of this question.
For question (a), would it be correct to simply look at the p-value alone? treatment B is coded as 0, it 'disappears' in the logit equation hence I am confused. My answer is:  p=0.04 < 0.05, hence there was a statistically significant association between type of treatment and remission. Is this correct/wrong?

For question (b), how can I compare the probabilities if treatment B 'disappears' in the equation?

Will appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For regression in general, including logistic regression, including dummy variables as independent variables entails having a *reference group*. That is, you you have dummies for (M-1) groups, where M is the total number of groups, and one of the groups doesn't get a dummy - that's the reference group. Note that female is also a reference group here. [See below where I explain why this has to be the case].

In this case, B is the reference group. So the coefficient on Treatment A can be interpreted as "the difference between A and the reference group, B". So the coefficient on Treatment A is, in effect, a coefficient recording the difference between the groups. As you've picked up there, if this coefficient is significant, then there's a significant difference between the treatment groups.

As for part b, keep in mind that the coefficient gives you the difference between A and B. The coefficient is negative. That doesn't mean that the probability of remission in Treatment A is negative (how could it?) Rather, it means that the probability of remission in Treatment A is *smaller* than the probability in Treatment B - everything is relative to the reference group.

Why does there have to be a reference group? This has to do with multicollinearity. Imagine we had a variable for Treatment A, another variable for Treatment B, and the Intercept (which is basically including a 1 as an independent variable). Since everyone is either Treatment A or Treatment B, we know that Treatment A + Treatment B = 1. So when we try to estimate the regression, it gets confused. Setting the coefficient on Treatment A to -.5, the coefficient on Treatment B to 0, and the coefficient on the Intercept to .2 (let's imagine that's what it is) is the *exact same* as setting the coefficient on Treatment A to -.3, the coefficient on Treatment B to .2, and the coefficient on Intercept to .4. And there are infinite such exactly-the-same combinations. It can't pick one, so it doesn't know what to do. We have to drop one of these terms from the model in order for it to be able to pick just one solution to estimate the model.

Comment: Also, it wasn't super important to the question so I didn't mention it, but just to clear up any potential confusion: the coefficient on Treatment A does not imply that A is 50% less likely than B to have remission. The magnitude of the coefficient relates to how Treatment A affects the logistic index function, not the probability itself, and is generally not directly interpretable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed and clear explanation :)

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to check the "Accepted Answer" checkmark on my answer if you're satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that the coefficient given by logistic regression models are often "log odds". If you can check what function is used to get the coefficients... and IF the function is the "logit function" then it is definitely "log odds".

the problem is that log odds are almost impossible to understand intuitively so you must convert them to "regular odds" if you want the numbers to mean anything to you. you can convert log odds to "regular" odds using exponentiation- e^(-0.5) = 0.61 odds.

This means treatment group A has less odds of remission than treatment group B by a factor of .6.

you can also find probability with the equation (odds / (1 + odds)).
so ( e^(-0.5) / 1 + (e^(-0.5)) ) = probability of 0.378.

so treatment group A has a probability of remission of 0.378.

and treatment group B has a probability of remission of 0.622.